# Global variables for Nodes

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, global-variables

I'm trying to create a simple program to insert words into a `Linked List`, yet I'm having a very hard time with understanding the global pointers that represent the `head` and `next` `Nodes`.

From what I understand, if I were to have a `struct` such as:

```
typedef struct NODE
{
    char *item;
    struct Node *next; 

} Node, *Node_ptr;
```

Then I could create global variables simply by declaring them underneath the `typedef`:

```
struct Node_ptr* head = NULL; 
struct Node_ptr* next = NULL;
```

But do I assign them to `NULL` immediately? Or do that in a method such as `main`? Also, do I have to have the `struct` in front of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But do I assign them to NULL immediately? Or do that in a method such as main?

Pointers defined at file-scope (what you call global) will be automatically initialized to `NULL` if you don't put an explicit initializer. So initializing them by assignment in `main` is redundant.

> Also, do I have to have the struct in front of it?

With your definition type and alias type defintion, there are 3 valid (and equivalent) ways how you can declare such pointers:

```
/* The = NULL initializer is optional at file-scope */
Node_ptr bla = NULL; 
Node *bla = NULL; 
struct NODE *bla = NULL;
```

(but not you cannot use `struct Node_ptr* head = NULL;` which is invalid.)

Comment: Thank-you!! So would it also be redundant to create a `*Node_ptr` in the `struct`, because I can simply create a pointer later in the code by inserting an asterisk in front of my `Node` variable?

Comment: @user180708 yes and for different reasons I'm also among those who think it's a bad practice to `typedef` pointers (the `Node_ptr` declaration).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the correct way would be:

```
typedef struct NODE
{
    char *item;
    struct NODE *next; // Notice here

} Node, *Node_ptr;
```

And the above code is equivalent to

```
struct NODE 
{
    char *item;
    struct NODE *next; 
};

typdef struct NODE Node , *Node_ptr;
```

Then, you only have to declare a `struct NODE` variable with `Node`, `struct NODE*` with `Node_ptr`, like this:

```
Node_ptr head = NULL; 
Node_ptr next = NULL;
```

I think it'd be a good practice to initialize it to `NULL` when you declare it.  But it's also fine if you do that in `main`.